# How can we insert nifi flowfile content as a blob file into oracle database

Tags: apache-nifi

I need to insert nifi flow file content as a blob file into my oracle database, let say below is my table columns.
id(this i will get as an nifi attribute),name(this also I will get as an attribute), and data(this contains my flow file content, I want this as a blob file). could you please help to achieve this using nifi.
my table is like below

```
id,name,data
1,aaa,some blob file
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best choice still scripting...

use ExecuteGroovyScript processor

declare properties:

```
SQL.mydb       = <select connection to database here>
SQL_STATEMENT  = insert into MyTable (name, data) values (:p_name, :p_data)
```

and use following as "script body" property:

```js
import groovy.sql.Sql

def ff = session.get()
if(!ff) return

ff.read{ rawIn->
  def params = [
    p_name : ff."Attribute name", //get flow file attribute by name
    p_data : Sql.BLOB( rawIn ),   //use input stream as BLOB sql parameter
  ]
  SQL.mydb.execute(params, SQL_STATEMENT.getValue()) //execute statement defined in properties
}
REL_SUCCESS << ff //just transfer flow file to success
```

Links:

- [more about groovy script in nifi](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-groovyx-nar/1.25.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.groovyx.ExecuteGroovyScript/additionalDetails.html)
- [groovy.sql.Sql class](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html)

Comment: thank you @daggett, i have used now PUTSQL processor and able to save the data into database, only one doubt is i am reading flow file content as an attribute and that attribure i am saving into the db column,but the flow file content is huge and when saving it into an attribute , the attribute has contains only part of the flow file content, could you please help me how can i make my flow file content as a blob object and save it into the sql table , thank you

Comment: when i use your script and execute, i am getting no signature of Method,groovy.sql.Osql.execute() is applicable for arguments types...., i am sorry unable to send complete error stack here, i guess some issue with p_data : Sql.BLOB( rawIn )

Comment: is this "rawIn" predefined or do i need to replace it with anything else in my code

Comment: `rawIn` is defined here: `ff.read{ rawIn->` and it represents the flowfile content as input stream.  could you please show more from error message?  `is applicable for arguments types....` - what's after this? i don't need full stack trace just full message.

Comment: is applicable for argument types: (LinkedHashMap, org.apache.nifi.attribute.expression.language.StandardPropertyValue) values: [[TBL_ID:11, CUST_ID:333, data:groovy.sql.Sql$31@54aadb5a], ...]
Possible solutions: execute(groovy.lang.GString), execute(java.lang.String), execute(java.lang.String, [Ljava.lang.Object;), execute(java.lang.String, java.util.List), execute(java.util.Map, java.lang.String), execute(groovy.lang.GString, groovy.lang.Closure)

Comment: If it doesn't work, could you please suggest me how can i use PUTSQL to save the complete flow file content into table as a blob file

Comment: sorry. i missed getValue in `SQL_STATEMENT.getValue()`. updated the answer

Comment: thank you so much your kindness, you made my day happy, its working :)

Comment: Hi daggett, i have raised one more stack over flow doubt, could you please help me if you have any idea. Thank you

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78184286/how-to-convert-flow-file-content-into-byte-array-and-zip-and-then-save-it-into