# How to convert flow file content into byte[] array and zip and then save it into database as a blob file in apache nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a flow file as like below and now i want to convert it as byte array and then make a zip out of this and then save it into a database as a blob file. Thank you so much for any help.

```
A   300 AAAAA
A   301 BBBBB
A   302 DDDDD
A   303 EEEEE
A   305 HHHHH
A   306 OOOOO
```

My flow file content size is maximum 500 MB, i am keeping here sample one

Answer (score 0):

there is a processor [`CompressContent`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.25.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.CompressContent/index.html) that could compress flowfile content for example gzip.

As for me, gzip format is appropriate for a single-file archive.

I remember one option for zip file - [`MergeContent`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.25.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.MergeContent/index.html) - it's dezigned to put multiple files into archive. Hopefully you can set `Maximum Number of Entries = 1` to zip just one file.

So, before storing data into a database call any of those processors.

Comment: Thank you daggett, i need to convert the flow file content as byte [] array, could you please help if you have any idea how can i achieve it please

Comment: it's always a byte array

Comment: Hi @daggett, I have posted one more doubt on the nifi with groovy script, could you please help me to achieve this. Thank you so much.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56561191/how-to-compare-two-csv-file-in-nifi